# How to stretch the image till top in android

Tags: java, android, json, layout

[image]

I am trying to stretch the image till the top in layout. But I couldn't achieve it. Any help is appreciated.

I want to move this image at the top. so there is no space between the top and image. Right now there is space on top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fafaf8"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"



    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titlePic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nebcaplivebanner"

        >

    </ImageView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="#C0C0C0"
        />






</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout XML file ?

Comment: @cesarmarch I have added the XML

Comment: @pal are you sure that banner image doesn't need cropped from the top? You have the background of the LinearLayout set as `#fafaf8` but I am picking up `#F4F4F4` using a color picker

Answer (score 0):

**try to use -**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titlePic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nebcaplivebanner"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

That's what **fitXY** is supposed to do. You can try with **centerInside** if you don't want to crop your image, or **centerCrop** if you want to fill all the space (and cropping your image).

Comment: That didn't fix though

Comment: try to add android:gravity="top" in LinearLayout

Comment: No, it didn't fix. It only moves till the top of linearLayout. LinearLayout itself doesn't stretch to top So in this condition, how can we achieve it by just moving to the top.

Comment: try to change **LinearLayout** color from this **#fafaf8** to any dark color like **black**, **blue**, etc. and check is there any space between ImageView and LinearLayout or it is just an image problem in ImageView.

Comment: as you sad your LinearLayout is not at the top then you can give **android:layout_gravity="top"** in LinearLayout also try **fitsSystemWindows=”true”**

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using scaleType fitxy

```
 <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/titlePic"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:src="@drawable/nebcaplivebanner" />
```

for detail ScaleType property:
https://abhiandroid.com/ui/scaletype-imageview-example.html
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Comment: I added the scaleType but still same issue. My entire layout is not stretched to the top. So in this case, Can image be stretched to the top over the layout then?

Comment: Are you sure the image doesn't contain any kind of top padding ? Try to change the background color of the ImageView to see if the top space is included in the ImageView or not.